# Android transition from RIGHT-TOP to LEFT-BOTTOM?

Tags: android, android-transitions

Im question if are possible create a transition from RIGHT-TOP to LEFT-BOTTOM?

have a examples for

for right

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <translate xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:duration="100"
        android:fromXDelta="-100%p"
        android:interpolator="@android:anim/linear_interpolator"
        android:toXDelta="0" />
```

to left

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

    <translate
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:duration="500"
        android:fromXDelta="100%p"
        android:toXDelta="0" 
        android:interpolator="@android:anim/linear_interpolator" />
```

any example?

Comment: I'm too lazy to do the actual code but why not add a fromYDelta and toYDelta to those samples?  If you have the y delta saying go top to bottom and the x delta saying go left to right you will have something coming in from the top left of the screen going down to the right.